# Subtracting multiple columns and appending results in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of sensor data, for which some columns are measurements and some columns are sensor bias.  For example, something like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1.0,2.0,3.0],'y':[4.0,5.0,6.0],
                 'dx':[0.25,0.25,0.25],'dy':[0.5,0.5,0.5]})
```

> ```
>     dx   dy    x    y
> 0  0.25  0.5  1.0  4.0
> 1  0.25  0.5  2.0  5.0
> 2  0.25  0.5  3.0  6.0
> ```

I can add a column to the table by subtracting the bias from the measurement like this:

```
df['newX'] = df['x'] - df['dx']
```

> ```
>     dx   dy    x    y  newX
> 0  0.25  0.5  1.0  4.0  0.75
> 1  0.25  0.5  2.0  5.0  1.75
> 2  0.25  0.5  3.0  6.0  2.75
> ```

But I'd like to do that for many columns at once.  This doesn't work:

```
df[['newX','newY']] = df[['x','y']] - df[['dx','dy']]
```

for two reasons, it seems.

- When subtracting DataFrames the column labels are used to align the subtraction, so I wind up with a 4 column result `['x', 'y', 'dx', 'dy']`.
- It seems I can insert a single column into the DataFrame using indexing, but not more than one.

Obviously I can iterate over the columns and do each one individually, but is there a more compact way to accomplish what I'm trying to do that is more analogous to the one column solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DataFrames generally align operations such as arithmetic on column and row indices. Since `df[['x','y']]` and `df[['dx','dy']]`  have different column names, the `dx` column is not subtracted from the `x` column, and similiarly for the `y` columns.

In contrast, if you subtract a NumPy array from a DataFrame, the operation is done elementwise since the NumPy array has no Panda-style indices to align upon.

Hence, if you use `df[['dx','dy']].values` to extract a NumPy array consisting of the values in `df[['dx','dy']]`, then your assignment can be done as desired:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1.0,2.0,3.0],'y':[4.0,5.0,6.0],
                 'dx':[0.25,0.25,0.25],'dy':[0.5,0.5,0.5]})
df[['newx','newy']] = df[['x','y']] - df[['dx','dy']].values
print(df)
```

yields

```
     dx   dy    x    y  newx  newy
0  0.25  0.5  1.0  4.0  0.75   3.5
1  0.25  0.5  2.0  5.0  1.75   4.5
2  0.25  0.5  3.0  6.0  2.75   5.5
```

---

Be ware that if you were to try assigning a NumPy array (on the right-hand side)
to a DataFrame (on the left-hand side), the column names specified on the left must already exist.

In contrast, when assigning a DataFrame on the right-hand side to a DataFrame on the left, new columns can be used since [in this case](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L2413) Pandas zips the keys (new column names) on the left with the columns on the right and assigns values in column-order instead of by aligning columns:

```
            for k1, k2 in zip(key, value.columns):
                self[k1] = value[k2]
```

Thus, using a DataFrame on the right

```
df[['newx','newy']] = df[['x','y']] - df[['dx','dy']].values
```

works, but using a NumPy array on the right

```
df[['newx','newy']] = df[['x','y']].values - df[['dx','dy']].values
```

does not.

Comment: That did it.  I'd tried using `.values` for both arguments to the subtraction and it complained that 'newx' and 'newy' weren't in the index.  The difference being, I presume, that if I use `.values` on both I'm assigning a numpy array but if I only use `.values` on the second I'm assigning a DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When the value on the right is a DataFrame, `_setitem_array` follows [a different code path](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L2413) than when the right-hand side is a NumPy array. When it is a NumPy array, it looks for columns `newx` and `newy` in `df.columns`, fails to find them, and thus raises `KeyError`. So using a NumPy array (on the right) is possible only when the columns referred to on the left-hand side already exist in `df`.