# Python Dataframe Sum/Subtract Many Columns to Many Coumns in one line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to sum many columns to many columns in a data frame.

My code:

```
df = 
    A1 B1  A2  B2
0  15  30  50  70
1  25  40  60  80
# I have many columns like this. I want to do something like this A1-A2, B1-B2, etc 
# My approach is 
first_cols = [A1,B1]
sec_cols = [A2,B2]
# New column names
sub_cols = [A_sub,B_sub]
df[sub_cols] = df[first_cols] - df[sec_cols]
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed , placement implies 1
```

Expected output:

```
df = 
    A1 B1  A2  B2  A_sub  B_sub
0  15  30  50  70  -35     -40
1  25  40  60  80  -35     -40
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy Yes! I edited my q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419286/subtracting-multiple-columns-and-appending-results-in-pandas-dataframe). In Dataframes generally the arithmetic operations are aligned on column and row indices. Since you are tring to subtract different columns, pandas doesn't carry out the operation. So, `df[sub_cols] = df[first_cols] - df[second_cols]` won't work.

However, if you were to use numpy array and do the operation, pandas carries it out elementwise. So, `df[sub_cols] = df[first_cols] - df[second_cols].values` will work and give you the expected result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {"A1":[15,25], "B1": [30, 40], "A2":[50,60], "B2": [70, 80]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
first_cols = ["A1", "B1"]
second_cols = ["A2", "B2"]

sub_cols = ["A_sub","B_sub"]

df[sub_cols] = df[first_cols] - df[second_cols].values

print(df)

   A1  B1  A2  B2  A_sub  B_sub
0  15  30  50  70    -35    -40
1  25  40  60  80    -35    -40
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also pull it off with a groupby on the columns:

```
subtraction = (df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis = 1)
                 .agg(np.subtract.reduce, axis = 1)
                 .add_suffix("_sub")
                )

df.assign(**subtraction) 
   A1  B1  A2  B2  A_sub  B_sub
0  15  30  50  70    -35    -40
1  25  40  60  80    -35    -40
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want. If you want one column that's A1-A2 and another that's B1-B2, you can do `df[[A1,A,2]].sub(df[[B1,B2]])`.